# Calculating the amount of heat extracted in a cycle in P-V diagram

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

The question goes like this: There's a thermodynamic cycle of an engine, operating with an ideal monoatomic gas. What'll be the amount of heat extracted from the source in a single cycle?
[image]

**My Approach:**
The work done by the gas is the area enclosed by the cycle,
$$\Delta W = P_0 V_0$$
By the first law of thermodynamics,
$$\Delta U = \Delta Q - \Delta W$$
Since, in a cycle $\Delta U = 0$,
$$\Delta Q = \Delta W = P_0 V_0$$

But the book says that the answer is $(13/2)P_0V_0$. Where I'm possibly going wrong?

Comment: I think they mean you to calculate "heat exhausted by the engine to the cold bath" not "net heat exchanged with both baths".

Comment: You have to calculate the heat exchanged for each process (each line in the graph) and add them up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't solve the problem but I will tell you why you are wrong.
The question asks to find the **heat extracted from the source**,your reasoning says **heat extracted from the source** is equal to total work done by the system in a single cycle.
This is clearly against 2nd law of thermodynamics that you cannot convert all of the heat taken from the source to work.
So whats wrong?

Heat extracted from the source is **not equal to** heat added to the system during the whole process ,because some of the heat extracted from the source is wasted and released to the surrounding.

Comment: By the way complete  answer is given here http://www.physicsplus.in/2014_04_01_archive.html?m=1

Comment: One more thing that I want to clarify is that why heat extracted is represented by the upward vertical portion and the rightward horizontal portion of the graph, as per the answer given in the link.

Comment: @Shuvam Shah :http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/engcyc.html#c2

Comment: Apply 1st law for each step and you will find the answer.

Comment: In the first link, it is mentioned that the upward vertical portion and rightward horizontal portion represent heat extraction, but in the HyperPhysics link it is mentioned that these two portions actually represent heat addition and the other parts represent heat extraction. So which link is correct? I'm confused. When exactly can I say that the certain part of a P-V diagram shows heat extraction/addition?

Comment: @Shuvam :Both are correct ,**extraction of heat by the gas from the SOURCE**  is different from **extraction of heat from the system**.

Comment: In the hyper physics website they talked about extraction of heat **from the system** ,but ultimately they are talking about the same physics.